# InDesign: undeletable # character appearing after having suppressed a table of contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, typesetting, table-of-contents, character

I'm currently working on a draft of a book to which I bring orthographic corrections before publication.

Here is the problem I come across.

The draft sent by the author contains a table of contents that I want to remove ( in order to rewrite it afterwards).

However, when I try to suppress this table of contents ( using selection, then " cut") the character " # " appears in place of the suppressed text; and this character cannot be deleted ( at least I cannot delete it).

Could you please tell me how comes this "#" appears , and how I could get rid of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be an empty text box placeholder introduced via the master page. Check what you have on the master page.

Alternatively, you can do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the page where you have that trailing "#". This should possibly unlock a text box introduced via the master page and then you could probably delete it.

If the above won't work, trying checking if there are any locked layers and/or locked objects on the page, which main contain an empty text box.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, that what you're seeing is the *End of Story* symbol, which is a "#".

When *hidden characters* are shown, a "#" is present as the last character in *all* text stories.

[image]

It can't be deleted and it isn't visible in the final PDF or on print.

To avoid seeing it you can use *Type > Show/Hide Hidden Characters* (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) to toggle the visibility of hidden characters or you can just press <kbd>W</kbd> to toggle between *Normal* and *Preview* mode.

Comment: Every end of story "#" belongs to a text box somewhere, so it most likely _can_ be deleted. The question is not about hiding or ignoring the "#', but in fact deleting the "#".

Comment: @Lucian, yeah I know, but I think it's unclear whether the OP deleted the text content of a text frame or deleted the frame itself. Just wanted to explain what the "#" is and then maybe it's not needed to delete it anymore.